# Show content div/section from external website on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to display external website contents based on dropdown select.

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="option1">Premiere League</option>
    <option value="option2">UEFA Champions League</option>
    <option value="option3">Serie A</option>
</select>
```

if option1 is select i want to display the content of http://goal.com `section.tab-content.schedule`which is a league schedule of Premiere League

if option2 is selected, it will display league schedule of UEFA from http://goal.com

how can i achieve this using jQuery/javascript

Comment: on the same page or in new tab

Comment: Bear in mind that the copyright (or terms of service) of other websites might not permit reusing their content on other websites. I don't know if this is the case for goal.com but chances are high...